# IBM Watson Movie Conversation Agent hosted inside Bluemix cloud: Strange situation

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, movie

IBM Watson Movie Conversation Agent hosted inside Bluemix cloud: Strange situation:

*I made the exact two copies of this IBM Watson Movie Conversation Agent inside Bluemix cloud during last several days. The demo open source code is on Github.

*The strange situation:
One of the above bots runs without problems here:
https://moviebotdev.mybluemix.net/#/chatting

Another copy like the above cannot load the content here:
https://moviebot.mybluemix.net/#/chatting

The above two apps both have been running over one day already. Each of the above apps is given 128mb memory.

Any suggestions and thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont' have a direct answer, but "Dialog" the chat component in that demo is deprecated. You should be using "Conversation" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of work, we found the following problem with this Watson Movie Assistant Demo app code: It is not engineered to work with Windows 10 Edge browser.  After we launched the demo app in chrome browser and then edited the code in Edge browser, the saved code cannot be displayed in any browser.  Now this demo app can run in major browsers, but it cannot be displayed on ipad. Anybody had this problem ? Any suggestions on this?
moviebotdev09.mybluemix.net

Comment: We want to hear the disputes to this reply from this person who marked down this answer.  This answer proved to be correct so far several times in my work.

Comment: About Watson Movie Assistant Demo app code: Another Bluemix user in our team deployed the above code in his account, the same situation happened like the above situation: This demo app can run in major browsers, but it cannot be displayed on several browsers in mobile devices. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Adding to the above comments, the screen on mobile devices " Loading, please wait" .

Answer (score 0):

Several things can cause the situation.

One, your watson's services must be linked correctly. Maybe it is not on your dashboard.
Two, there's maybe a java version and node.js version.
Three, a few days ago, IBM made official that dialog will be deprecated. Making new instance of dialog service impossible I remember well.

Hope you'll find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for these info.  I like to add the following:

Comment: # Based on the following Watson notice, Bluemix user still can create new instance of Dialog service API before Sept.8/2016 and will continue to function until August 9, 2017..  

"The IBM Watson™ Dialog service will be deprecated on August 15, 2016. The service will be retired on September 8, 2016, after which no new instances of the service can be created, though existing instances of the service will continue to function until August 9, 2017. "
http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/dialog/

Comment: # Now, we encountered the following problem:
On Aug. 26, I connected the following demo apps to the movie database. For a while, it can display movies from the movie database. But then, the Watson cloud API stopped loading since Aug.28.
moviebotdev.mybluemix.net
This situation is different from the above public announcement. As I created the Dialogue Service new instance before the deadline Sept.8/2016

Comment: Anybody from IBM Watson API Cloud team can help your customer here?

Comment: If you need help from cloud team, open a ticket. Click on your name on the dashboard and there should be a "get Help". Again though, Dialog is going away and Conversation is the new system (and different)  I would focus on latter.

Comment: Hi Simon, following the instruction on the above space, the Bluemix users are told to post Q here.